# Find index of elements in array that contain a keyword

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array and I need to get the index of the elements which contain the word "milk".

```
array = ["bread ciabatta", "milk natural", "milk chocolate", "cookies chocolate", "bread banana", "bread focaccia", "milk strawberry"]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

One of the ways is to use `enumerate` inside a `list-comprehension`:

```
array = ["bread ciabatta", "milk natural", "milk chocolate", "cookies chocolate", "bread banana", "bread focaccia", "milk strawberry"]
indices = [i for i, s in enumerate(array) if 'milk' in s]
print(indices) # output [1, 2, 6]
```

Learn about `enumerate`: [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 2):

```
res = []
for i, value in enumerate(array):
    if('milk' in value):
        res.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

array = pd.Series(["bread ciabatta", "milk natural", "milk chocolate", "cookies chocolate", "bread banana", "bread focaccia", "milk strawberry"])
array.str.match(r".*milk ")
```

This returns a boolean mask.

If you need indices you can do:

```
array.index[array.str.match(r".*milk ")]
```